# Detect Multiple SMS sent due to length of content

Tags: android, sms, contentobserver

I have setup a background service to `registerContentObserver` to get notified whenever an SMS is sent. Upon receiving this event, I would increment a variable to know the count of messages sent. This is working as expected.

When someone sends SMS with more than 140 characters, the mobile carrier would treat this as multiple SMS, but it seems that I get only 1 callback for the sent message. This is causing my app to miss counting some messages.

Is there any proper way to know how many messages were actually sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an app is responsible for writing its own messages to the Provider, it's most likely going to write the whole message in one go, regardless of whether the message must be sent as multipart. This would be why your Observer is often firing only once for each complete message, no matter how big.

Since KitKat, the system will automatically save the outgoing messages for any non-default apps, and for multipart messages, each part will be saved individually, firing your Observer each time. Of course, this doesn't help for anything prior to KitKat, or if a default app saves its own messages on later versions.

One possibility is to fetch the message body in your `ContentObserver`, and determine how many message parts it would've been split into. The `SmsMessage.calculateLength()` method can do this for us. It returns an `int` array, the first element of which will have the message count for the given text.

For example, using the old `onChange(boolean)` method, to support API < 16:

```
private class SmsObserver extends ContentObserver {
    private static final Uri SMS_SENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_BODY = "body";
    private static final String[] PROJECTION = {COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_BODY};

    // You might want to persist this value to storage, rather than
    // keeping a field, in case the Observer is killed and recreated.
    private int lastId;

    public SmsObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        Cursor c = null;
        try {
            // Get the most recent sent message.
            c = getContentResolver().query(SMS_SENT_URI, PROJECTION, null,
                                           null, "date DESC LIMIT 1");
            if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {

                // Check that we've not already counted this one.
                final int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID));
                if (id == lastId) {
                    return;
                }
                lastId = id;

                // Get the message body, and have the SmsMessage
                // class calculate how many parts it would need.
                final String body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_BODY));
                final int numParts = SmsMessage.calculateLength(body, false)[0];

                // Add the number of parts to the count,
                // however you might be doing that.
                addToCount(numParts);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (c != null) {
                c.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Should you be supporting API 16 and above, we can use the `onChange(boolean, Uri)` overload, and things get a little simpler, since we don't necessarily need to keep track of the last message ID.

```
@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        // type=2 restricts the query to the sent box, so this just
        // won't return any records if the Uri isn't for a sent message.
        c = getContentResolver().query(uri, PROJECTION, "type=2", null, null);
        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            final String body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_BODY));
            final int numParts = SmsMessage.calculateLength(body, false)[0];

            addToCount(numParts);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (c != null) {
            c.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing solution with code. I see that you have faced similar issues as me with regards to the lastMessageId and as my app supports API 8 and upwards, I would check the first option. +1 for the detailed explanation. My app code is located at https://github.com/midhunhk/message-counter

Comment: Yeah, it takes a little more work to handle API < 16, but I see that you already know that. :-) I noticed that you're using the `protocol` column to determine if a message is a sent message. You might consider using the `type` column instead. Type 2 is _sent_, type 1 is _inbox_. You can see all of the message types on [this page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.html). They weren't made official until API 19, but the values were always the same. Lemme know if I can clarify anything. Hope it works for you. Cheers!

Comment: Cheers! That's good information to know. It was very hard to get this much done since the SMS API documentation was not public. Thanks much for the detailed and quick reply.

Comment: I just realized something. In my example for API < 16, you'll notice that the URI used is `content://sms/sent`. If you query that URI, rather than just `content://sms`, you don't need to check either the `type` or the `protocol`. The `/sent` portion automatically restricts the query to `type=2`. That's why I don't have any checks for the `type` in the code there. Sorry I didn't think of that when I commented my suggestion earlier. I just wasn't thinking thoroughly about the code. Whichever way you'd want to do it, though, should work the same. Just another tip.

Comment: I think I'm using `content://sms/sent`, but not sure if I need to check `protocol` to identify as a sent message. Any idea why we are getting multiple call backs with the same `id`?

Comment: If you query `content://sms/sent`, then you don't need to check `type`/`protocol`. It's restricted to `type=2`. Also, you don't really get multiple callbacks for the same ID. You're registered for `content://sms`, so any change to any SMS table fires your Observer, like when _inbox_ and _draft_ messages are saved, too. The standard Provider has a table called _raw_, which it uses to stage and assemble messages temporarily. That's usually cleared after the messages have been sent, and that will fire your Observer at least one more time. It's a pain, 'cause you have to register `content://sms`.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out? I think I confused things by including a complete `ContentObserver` in the answer. Really, if your original code was working for you (except for the multipart count, of course), then you can just stick with the original, and only add the `SmsMessage.calculateLength()` stuff. Sorry if I made things more complicated than they needed to be.

Comment: Hey @mike, I am good with your response but was unable to implement and test out the changes. Been held up with work and another app project. Only the multipart count was not working earlier.